# How to stop all events inside an element from effecting the rest of the DOM

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating a simple text editor for my site. When a button is pressed it adds an emoji to the input. I'm trying to stop any interaction with the emoji selector from causing the input to lose focus.

Basically, I'm hoping there's some way to use .stopPropogation() on an element and all of its children.

It's possible there just isn't a way to do that.

```
popup.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
  console.log('clicked')
  e.stopPropagation()
})
```

This doesn't work

Comment: You will have to re-focus the input. Slap a ref on the element and then call `.focus()` on it

Comment: @DerekPollard It's not necessary to manually refocus - you can also call `preventDefault` on the `mousedown` event, if you want

Comment: @CertainPerformance that's not the vue way. you shouldn't be using custom listeners in Vue

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use vue's built in [refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs):

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data() {
  return {
    text: ''
  }
 },
 methods: {
  addEmoji() {
    this.text += ':)';
    this.$refs.textareaX.focus();
  }
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <textarea v-model="text" ref="textareaX"></textarea>
  <button @click="addEmoji">add smile</button>
</div>
```

This way, you're taking full advantage of vue and not trying to step out and set your own listeners (which can and will be reset when vue does a re-render)